# ColdFusion framework for Work Order System

Tags: frameworks, coldfusion, cfml

I have been working with ColdFusion for the last two years. Until now, I have used only one framework: fusebox (an older framework). According to my next development requirement, I have to develop a "Work Order Software System", but using a ColdFusion framework. My question is  which framework should I use? I am a bit confused about which one to use.

Comment: Most CFML developers these days use [FW/1](http://fw1.riaforge.org/), [ColdBox](http://coldbox.org) or [cfWheels](http://cfwheels.org) - see this existing question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361951/picking-a-coldfusion-mvc-framework

Comment: Here is another existing question about ColdFusion Frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797974/the-best-oo-framework-in-coldfusion9

Comment: I still love FuseBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like object oriented technology then I will refer Model-Glue and Coldbox. Model-Glue supports Ajax and jQuery but needs more efforts then Coldbox. both uses events to call the function. for more go to [model-glue](http://www.model-glue.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/11/5/ModelGlue--New-Flex-Integration-Features),[coldbox](http://www.coldbox.org/)
You need to read up on how views work, but this page of the docs summarises it succinctly:

http://docs.model-glue.com/wiki/ReferenceMaterials/ViewApi#ViewAPI

Specifically this code snippet:

```
<cfoutput>#viewcollection.getView("body")#</cfoutput>
```

It's probably a case of reading through the docs a bit, and reminding yourself about how model glue's implementation of MVC (specifically the V part, in your case!) works.

Comment: thanks coldfusiondevshop....its helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're from a Ruby on Rails background, then you'll love CFWheels - http://cfwheels.org/

Even if you're not, it's a great framework. My first and easy to get going with! Well documented and plenty of examples to get going with.