# What are the best practices for ColdFusion programming?

Tags: coldfusion, methodology

I have been doing web development using PHP and Python for years. Recently, I started to program in ColdFusion without any frameworks. To me it seems very messy so far, I mean very thing mixed together, no MVC (missed Django a lot).

I am not sure is there any light-weighted framework for ColdFusion. Otherwise, any suggestions on good practices when doing ColdFusion programming?

Comment: I believe it is all subjective but... [Picking a ColdFusion MVC Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3361951/1636917)

Comment: I know it's all subjective.

Comment: While it is certainly a valid question, it is not the best fit for SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find these links helpful:-

[Univ. of Maryland ColdFusion Programming Standards](http://www.mdcfug.org/articles.cfm)

and [SBA ColdFusion Programming Standards](http://www.scribd.com/doc/17091861/Cold-Fusion-Coding-Standards) and

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion.html

Comment: I'd add: http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/DevelopmentBestPractices.cfm

Comment: I wonder why the U of Maryland site said that cfoutput was faster than cfloop.  Not curious enough to test it, but mildly curious.

Comment: @DanBracuk It was written in 2000, so  would ignore it.